# Installing Sphinx on Linux VPS

Tags: sphinx, vps

After hours of searching Google and StackOverflow, I haven't been able to resolve this issue...

I'm trying to install Sphinx Search on my VPS, but I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. All I know is that this search feature is extremely important to my project.

I've tried the following commands in puTTy to unpack the Sphinx tarball:

`tar xzvf sphinx-2.0.6-release.tar.gz`

`tar -xzvf sphinx-2.0.6-release.tar.gz`

It says there's no such file or directory. I know the file is there because I put it there myself, so I'm assuming now that I've misunderstood what is going on here.

Can someone get me past this step so that I can get lost on the next one?

Comment: What is your Linux ditro? Please let us know the output of cat /etc/*release

Comment: @vfedorkov output of  cat /etc/*release is  `CentOS release 6.3 (Final)  CentOS release 6.3 (Final)  CentOS release 6.3 (Final)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It says there's no such file or directory. I know the file is there because I put it there myself,

Probably not in the right folder - need to 'cd' into the folder containing the file.

But as you dont seem that familer with linux, would suggest using the RPM file instead - so dont have to compile from source.

get the RPM from 
http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/
and then upload that. Then use "yum localinstall nameofrpmfile.rpm"

Check the output of `uname -a` to find if you have 64bit or 32bit system. If mentions x86_64 you have 64bit, and so want the x86_64 RPM file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "'cd' into the folder containing the file". Checked uname -a and it's a 64 bit system, so I've got that RPM file. I uploaded it and tried using "yum localinstall sphinx-2.0.6-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm", at which time it said I need root access.  I tried signing in as su - login, input password, and it looked like it would work, but then again it said must have root access. How do you login as root in puTTy? I can't find anything on the web that says how. I'm using Plesk as my control panel

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but it sounds like we are going to be a limited use until you gain more linux command line experience. So either hire a consultant to finish the job for you, or set aside some time and do some learning - maybe something like http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/ .

Comment: Actually, I've had a little bit of success after looking at that site for a few minutes. I've managed to login as root and try the "yum localinstall...", but here's what I get: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Setting up Local Package Process
Cannot open: sphinx-2.0.6-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Nothing to do  Any ideas on what this might mean?

Comment: I went through and learned some of the linux commands, and continue to use that resource when I need help, and I'm on my way! Having trouble with understanding some things but I'm getting it figured out a little at a time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Like they say - no pain, no gain.